# How to add leading zeros to my data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a varchar column that has variations of following data:

`WKKT-FM, 2/21
WKKT-FM, 1/24-2/14 
WKKT-FM, 3/14-3/21, 4/11-4/18
IKKT-FM, 12/29-1/12, 1/26-2/09, 6/01-6/15`

And so on.  I need to place leading zeros in front of days and months.  As you can see some of them already have leading zeros.

I tried looking for #/ or -#, but I have to account for some values that already have the leading zero.

A function would be preferable as I have to get this field via the SELECT statement.

What is an effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: you need leading zero for both month and day

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes, for both month and day

Comment: `IKKT-FM, 12/29-1/12, 1/26-2/09, 6/01-6/15` all these were stored in single column ?

Comment: @NoDisplayName Yes, they are all in a single column.

Comment: is this for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: I think you'll have to look for the position of the slash, then 2 characters before and 2 after.

Comment: @Donal Yes, for SQL Server 2005

Comment: Bah. The biggest challenge here is your data is not normalized. This is forcing you to struggle getting the data back the way you want so you have to resort to the achilles heel of sql server, the scalar function.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, but there is nothing I can do at this point - I am just the consumer of this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ugly, but it should work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_AddMissingZero
(
    @val    NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  @val = @val + ' ',
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 1/', ' 01/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 2/', ' 02/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 3/', ' 03/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 4/', ' 04/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 5/', ' 05/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 6/', ' 06/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 7/', ' 07/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 8/', ' 08/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 9/', ' 09/'),

            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 1-', ' 01-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 2-', ' 02-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 3-', ' 03-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 4-', ' 04-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 5-', ' 05-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 6-', ' 06-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 7-', ' 07-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 8-', ' 08-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, ' 9-', ' 09-'),            

            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-1/', '-01/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-2/', '-02/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-3/', '-03/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-4/', '-04/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-5/', '-05/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-6/', '-06/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-7/', '-07/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-8/', '-08/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-9/', '-09/'),

            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-1-', '-01-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-2-', '-02-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-3-', '-03-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-4-', '-04-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-5-', '-05-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-6-', '-06-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-7-', '-07-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-8-', '-08-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '-9-', '-09-'),

            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/1/', '/01/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/2/', '/02/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/3/', '/03/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/4/', '/04/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/5/', '/05/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/6/', '/06/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/7/', '/07/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/8/', '/08/'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/9/', '/09/'),

            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/1-', '/01-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/2-', '/02-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/3-', '/03-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/4-', '/04-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/5-', '/05-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/6-', '/06-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/7-', '/07-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/8-', '/08-'),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/9-', '/09-'),

            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/1 ', '/01 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/2 ', '/02 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/3 ', '/03 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/4 ', '/04 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/5 ', '/05 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/6 ', '/06 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/7 ', '/07 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/8 ', '/08 '),
            @val = REPLACE(@val, '/9 ', '/09 ')                                      

    RETURN Rtrim(@val)
END
GO
```

Comment: It almost works... it convert `0001, WKKT-FM, 2/7` as `0001, WKKT-FM, 02/7` - the day doesn't have the leading zero.  Not sure why since you do have `@val = REPLACE(@val, '/7 ', '/07 '),`

Comment: Oh, I see, you also had the space...that's why.

Comment: If I remove the space, than it also appends 0 to the ones that are two digit to begin with.

Comment: I edited my answer to handle this case, by adding a extra space at the end at the beginning. (Removing it at the end)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will take in a string, and return with the single digit numbers with a left padded Zero

```
CREATE FUNCTION PadNumberLeft (@WrkInfo VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OutputData VARCHAR(25) = ''
    DECLARE @iCount INT = 1

    WHILE @iCount <= LEN(@WrkInfo)
        BEGIN

            IF ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount, 1)) = 1 AND
                ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount + 1, 1)) = 1
                BEGIN
                    SET @OutputData = @OutputData + SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount, 3) 
                    SET @iCount = @iCount + 3
                END
            IF ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount, 1)) = 1 AND
                ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount + 1, 1)) = 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @OutputData = @OutputData + '0' + SUBSTRING(@WrkInfo, @iCount, 2) 
                    SET @iCount = @iCount + 1
                END

            SET @iCount = @iCount + 1
        END
    RETURN @OutputData 
END;
```